# How to cancel sleep mode of an iOS application?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an iOS application where the app is supposed to make a server request before going to background mode. I app should not wait for the response as that's not needed. The sole purpose of this request is that I need to keep the status of the app in my DB to know if the user is online/offline.

As the app goes to background, i make the server request and put the app into sleep mode by sleep(3) so that it can successfully finish the server call.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    //make a server call

    sleep(3) //so that app can submit request to server before closing
}
```

This works fine but if I open the app again (comes to foreground) before that sleep time has been finished, the app does not respond to any kind of user inputs/taps. Even the applicationDidBecomeActive method does not get called. It waits for that sleep time to finish that I had set before.

How can I cancel the sleep mode when the app becomes active?

Comment: You should never use `sleep` in your iOS code. Your best bet would be just to make the call when the app goes to background and hope that goes to your server. The sleep is not only unneeded, but it's highly discouraged, since it blocks all UI as well.

Comment: Is there any way to make a server request when the app is killed by the user?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `sleep`. Instead, make your server request using a URLSession that is suitable for background processing:

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: .background(withIdentifier: "foo"))
```